# Solving optimal apportionment

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrix-equations

I'm trying to solve the apportionment problem in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usS17.png):

1. There are four funds (F1, F2, F3 and F4) each with a fixed value.
2. There are two people (P1 and P2) that need certain amounts of money.
3. Each person can withdraw money from one or more funds but depending on the fund there is a maximum amount that can be taken.

The problem is to find one ore more solutions where all people receive the money they need.

I solved the problem programmatically but I'd like to know if there is a more elegant mathematical solution. I started with the idea of using a linear system of inequalities but I'm struggling defining it and I'm not even sure I'm on the right track (I'm not a mathematician).

I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

Alessandro

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Note that there is more money in the funds than the people require. Therefore there are many possible solutions. For example, you could just start with person 1, give them the money they need from the funds with lowest numbers (while respecting withdrawal constraints), then satisfy person 2 with the remaining funds, again starting with those with lowest number, and so on. To make this an optimization problem, you need to say what is to be minimized (objective function). Technically, we are finding a feasible solution to a set of linear inequalities.